# installing windows from bootcamp with image dvd

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I'm trying to install windows 7 with bootcamp. I get the following message, after mounting windows image (.iso)

> Insert your Windows installer disc and
>   wait a few seconds for the disc to be
>   recognized.

I did the same thing on the imac and it was fine, but now, on the macbook, osx seems not to recognize the dvd.

Do you know could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an ISO image with the Boot Camp Assistant. It only allows a disc, as:

1. You need to install it outside of Mac OS X
2. You cannot mount an image when Mac OS X is not running
3. Mac OS X's EFI bootloader only accepts physical storage media

Thus, you can only use a disc. To burn the ISO to a CD/DVD, mount the image, open disk utility, insert a blank disk and click on burn. After burning the disc, you should be able to use it for Boot Camp.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting up the iso image from a harddrive?